# How to keep DRY when I need to overload a method for all of my forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dry

On all of my C# forms, I have the following code:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        const int WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = 0x80;

        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle |= WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW;
        return cp;
    }
}
```

How would I remove this from each of my forms and keep my code clean?

Comment: Maybe you could use a base class and inherit your form from that (with the Base class of course inheriting from the Form class)?

Comment: Please use named constants (e.g. `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW`) in your code, rather than magic numbers. Much more readable, I don't have to look up what `0x80` means—and I can only do that because I understand the context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about a base class which inherits `Form` and overrides the whole `CreateParams` property. Then, the rest of concrete forms inherits your `CustomForm`.

Any form within your application will share this `CreateParams` implementation and, if some of them requires a specific implementation, an override in the concrete class will be enough! ;)

Comment: @Tim Polymorphism all the way! Thank you ;)

Comment: The op will remember this answer for the rest of his/her career. Simple and effective. OOP is awesome on occaision.

Answer (score 4):

Create a base class that will have this property, and have all your forms inherit from it. For example:

```
public class BaseForm : Form 
{
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams 
    {
        get { … }
    }
}

public class MyForm1 : BaseForm { … }
public class MyForm2 : BaseForm { … }
```

Comment: There are 2 problems here. The first is the missing override, the second is the fact that you can't define BaseForm as abstract if you want to use the VS Designer, since when you edit MyForm1 it creates (tries to create in this case) an instance of BaseForm, not of MyForm1 and fails.

Comment: @FrancescoBaruchelli How does `new MyForm1()` fail..? `abstract` means you cannot directly create instances of `BaseForm`, which is exactly the point. You can only create `MyForm1` and `MyForm2` that both have `CreateParams`.

Comment: You can create it, but the designer works differently. In the normal case (MyForm derived directly from Form) the designer create an instance of Form, then analyse the statements of InitializeComponent and applies them to this Form. There is never an instance of MyForm. Of course everything is fine with abstract at runtime, is just the VS designer that generates an exception

Comment: Ah, I see. No abstract then.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the current forms of yours have type of `CurrentForm`. It looks like that you don't want to change the code in `CurrentForm`, because if you want to do so, you can simply remove the line `cp.ExStyle |= 0x80;`. Your `CurrentForm` may also contain many other `Properties`, `Methods`, `Event handlers`, ... which should be inherited. In such a case, we can't inherit all the current forms from `Form` (the standard class in .NET). We should inherit all the forms from the `CurrentForm` as follow:

```
public class MediumForm : CurrentForm {
   protected override CreateParams CreateParams
   {
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle &= ~0x80;
        return cp;
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: How is this significantly different from the other two answers?

Comment: @Tim just edited, suppose `the current form` is type of `CurrentForm` and `CurrentForm` inherits from `Form3`, `Form3` inherits from `Form2`, `Form2` inherits from `Form1`, `Form1` inherits from `Form`. That situation would make it different. I know for sure that `CurrentForm` has `0x80` in `CreateParams.ExStyle`, I mean `CreateParams` of `CurrentForm` base type can be different from `Form's`. This way it should be safer. **However if the `CurrentForm` base type is `Form`, there is no difference.**

Comment: If a program is chaining inheritance that way I'd be thinking they had a serious design flaw (I've seen that done as a way to attempt to get around the single-inheritance restriction in .NET).  But I don't think OP intends on doing that and I don't think either of the other two questions were suggesting it.  It's an edge case, IMO - though it doesn't hurt to point it out.